# Site tabs reload

Tags: php, javascript, session, cookies

If I have for example 7 open tabs with user personal profile i browser, after session is going down user sees the alert confirmation does he wan't to continue his session or not, if not, session destroes and all 7 tabs with his personal profile should be loaded end php redirect them to login form.

here is the question, how can I determine that the session were destroed and we should reload tabs? Ajax is not good solution coz it's make a lot of queries to server

Answer (score 0):

I think AJAX would be the solution, there's no need to make a lot of queries. Just use a javascript callback function which is executed once each 5 minuts and checks if user has chosen to not continue his session. If yes, then redirect...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to use AJAX, which is the only available solution I know of for dynamic refresh/closing capabilities, you will have to check if the session exists each time the page is loaded to determine if the page should be reloaded or closed. You can do this by saving the session id in a cookie and comparing it each time the page is loaded. This will tell you if the session has ended and can allow you to reload it if I recall correctly.